# Lookup API NetBeans Platform + Maven: loosely coupled modules

Tags: netbeans-platform, loose-coupling

I'm developing a NetBeans platform application and want to use lookup api to get implementations for specific interfaces, still keeping everything loosely coupled.
But the lookup can't find any service provider.

Well, I created:

- a Module (A) that contains two Interfaces (Prot,Com) and a class to show some GUI.
- a Module (B) that contains an implementation of interface Prot
- a Module (C) that contains an implementation of interface COM.

To register an implementation i used *@ServiceProvider* annotation.
For Examble in Module B:

```
@ServiceProvider(service = Prot.class)
class ProtImpl implements Prot
{
   @Override
   ...
}
```

I defined the default-constructor, that is needed, if you use @ServiceProvider annotation.
I defined a dependency on Module A because B need to know something about the interface.

Lookup Examble in Module A:

```
private void printImplNames()
{
   Prot prot = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(Prot.class);
   prot.getName(); // <--- Null-Pointer
}
```

Now if I look up the implementation of interface Prot, I get a null pointer exception. With other words, there is no implementation registered. The lookup cant find any service provider.
Annotation processcor works fine, because files in META-INF/.../ directory were created.

The only thing that seems to work is to define a dependency on Module B in Module A **BUT** in this way the aspect of loosley coupled modules is lost.

I followed intructions on NetBeans Platform Website and NetBeans Platform 7 Book but nothing seems to work. Hope somebody can help me to solve that problem.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a working example for this situation located at GitHub.

https://github.com/flinkgutt/stackoverflow/tree/master/LooseCoupling

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, Christian!

So all i have to do while developing is define dependencies on all modules in projectname-app, am i right?

How to add new modules (let me say a new prot impl) after deployment than? Will the update center define dependency automatically?