# Maven Netbeans Application does not find ServiceProvider

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

The setup:
In our company, I try to migrate an Ant based Netbeans Application to Maven.
I have a Maven based Netbeans Platform Application and two Maven Module POM projects containing Netbeans modules.

```
|API (POM project)
 |-APIModule
  |-MyService.java
|Implementation (POM project)
 |-ImplModule (dependency on APIModule)
  |-MyServiceProvider.java (implements MyService)
|Application (Maven Netbeans Platform Application) (dependency on API and Implementation)
 |-branding
 |-netbeans-app (the application)
 |-viewer
  |-MyViewer.java (calls Lookup.getDefault().lookup(MyService.class)
```

API and Implementation are built using `<packaging>pom</packaging>`, and the dependencies are declared using

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>mavenprojectapi</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This way, I can easily swap out implementations for services in the `API` section, and build a new UI if I do not want to stick to the Netbeans Platform anymore.

The problem: In MyViewer, I call `Lookup.getDefault().lookup(MyService.class)`.

But it does not find an implementation of MyService.

I know that `@ServiceProvider` finds implementations if they were explicitly declared (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476310/lookup-api-netbeans-platform-maven-loosely-coupled-modules)), but that is not what I want.

The question: How can I find Service implementations defined through Lookup and ServiceProvider **that are defined in other module suites**?

**UPDATE**: It seems the transitive dependencies are not loaded from the Implementation project. What I can do is define a Netbeans aggregate module that has explicit dependencies on all implementation modules and declare it as a direct dependency in my Application. This way transitive dependencies are loaded and the ServiceProviders are found.

What I **want** though, is duplicate the "import cluster" functionality in Ant-based projects. There are goals described in the [official NBM plugin documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/), and clusters are built for single modules, but I do not know a way to access them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change the module type of the Implementation module to eager.

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
    <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    ...
    <configuration>
        <moduleType>eager</moduleType>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sadly this did not get rid of the problem. I edited and updated my question.